# Adding and removing from count when checkbox is checked/unchecked with javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm relatively new to JS, so I'm getting a little stuck with this:

Let's say I have 40 checkboxes, but a user can select no more than 10.

I have the checkboxes set out, labelled `checkbox1`, `checkbox2` etc right up to 40. The user cannot select more than 10. How would I go about doing this?

The way I thought of doing it would be like this, but I'm unsure whether or not this would work, due to obviously having 40 fields and then what if they uncheck one?

```
function checkValidation() {
  if (document.getElementById('checkbox1').isChecked()) {
    document.getElementById('validation').value() + 1;
  }
}
```

So every time it's checked, it would add 1 to the textbox validation and then I could do an if statement to say if `validation.value() > 8` then alert out to say they can't check anymore.
I think that's not the best way, as if they uncheck the box, my function won't take this in consideration?

Hopefully this makes sense, if anything needs clarification please let me know and I can explain further.

Comment: You're missing an `if` statement, mixing JavaScript with jQuery.

Comment: Please share your markup and create a working snippet demonstrating your issue using `<>`.

Comment: @Tushar sorry you're correct, fixed that.

Comment: @gurvinder372 sure, give me 2 mins and I will create a snippet.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a class on all your considered checkboxe, called for example `chk`.

Then you declare your count function :

```
function countCheck(){
    return $(".chk:checked").length;
}
```

Finally you add an event on your checkboxes click :

```
$(document).on("click",".chk",function(){
    var numberChecked = countCheck();
    //update your input
   $("#validation").val(numberChecked );
});
```

Comment: Sorry for my confusion, will this take in to account when the checkbox is then unchecked?

Comment: Yes, it does, since the `click`event is trigger whenever you check or uncheck the checkbox. Then, the `countCheck` function will count only the checked ones.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following way:

```js
$('#myBtn').click(function(){
  var countCheckd = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length;
  if(countCheckd >= 3){   
    console.log('You have 3 or more checked: ' +countCheckd);
  }
  else{
    console.log('You have less than 3 checked: ' +countCheckd);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" />1
<input type="checkbox" />2
<input type="checkbox" />3
<input type="checkbox" />4
<input type="checkbox" />5

<br><br>
<input type="button" id="myBtn" value="Check"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make an event of checkbox click and check for the count of each click, in below example if the **click is exceeded then 5** it gives an alert message and won't be allowed to click more checkboxes.

```js
$(function(){
    for(var i=0;i<=30;i++){
        $(".test").append("checkbox "+i+"<input type='checkbox' name='chk[]' class='check' id='check_"+i+"'><br />");
    }
})

$(document).on("click",".check",function(){
    var checked = $(".check:checked").length
    if(checked > 5){
        alert("Maximum 5");
        return false;
    } 
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='test'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function (e) {
    if ($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 10) {
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
        alert("Only 10 selection is allowed");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```js
// these are global variables
var checkBoxChecks = 0;
var maxChecks = 10;

$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function()
{
    // if the currently clicked checkbox is now checked
    if(this.checked)
    {
       if(checkBoxChecks < maxChecks) checkBoxChecks++;
       else
       {
           this.checked = false;
           alert("You have reached the maximum amount of " + maxChecks + " checks.");
       }
    }
    else checkBoxChecks--;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is unchecking previous checkbox if checked input's length more than 10:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function(){
  var max=0;
  var t=$(this);
  $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(){
    if($(this).data('oops')>max){
      max=$(this).data('oops');
    }
  });
  t.data('oops', (max+1));
  if($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length>10){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(){
      if($(this).data('oops')==max){
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Without adding global variable.

[See](https://jsbin.com/beridal/edit?js,output)